# postgres full text search word count

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

I've been messing around with full text search in postgres, and I was wondering, is it possible to return total word counts of all rows?

So, let's say you have

```
 text_col
 _______
 'dog'
 'dog cat'
 'dog bird dog'
```

the count of 'dog' should be four, the count of 'cat' should be one and bird should also be one.

Right now I have all the tsvectors saved to a gin indexed column as well.

Of course this would be across all rows where you could say something like

```
select max(ts_count(text_col_tsvector)) from mytable;
```

(I made that up, but I hope you get the general idea)

is it only possible to return the count of the lexeme, and if so, how does one return the dictionary (or array) of the lexeme returned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

how about:

```
select * from ts_stat('select text_col_tsvector from mytable')
```

Edit:
You mean:

```
with words as (
select regexp_split_to_table(text_column , E'\\W+') as word
from mytable
)
select word, count(*) as cnt from words group by 1 order by 2 desc
```

?

Comment: this is useful and gets me in the write direction, but this only returns lexemes. What I really need to know are the specific word counts, or failing that, return a dictionary (or array) of words associated with a specific lexeme.

Comment: This is 95% of what I wanted. I was hoping to use the indexed lexer, but I'm not sure it's possible to go backwards to the dictionary of words the lex references. I used what you have above and added to it slightly:  with words as (
select regexp_split_to_table(element_text , E'\\W+') as word
from mytable
),
word_lex as ( select word, count(*) as cnt,
to_tsvector('english', COALESCE(word,'')) as t
from words
group by 1 order by 2 desc )
select * from word_lex WHERE
t != ''

Comment: @JamesR if you use te 'simple' dictionary to build the tsvector column, the lexemes will be the actual words, and the first query will do the trick